# Is there a way to use the SpeechRecognizer API directly for speech input?

Tags: android, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

The Android Dev website provides an example of doing speech input using the built-in Google Speech Input Activity.  The activity displays a pre-configured pop-up with the mic and passes its results using `onActivityResult()`

My question:
Is there a way to use the `SpeechRecognizer` class directly to do speech input without displaying the canned activity?  This would let me build my own Activity for voice input.

Answer (score 57):

Here is the code using SpeechRecognizer class (sourced from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6316937/how-can-i-use-speech-recognition-without-the-annoying-dialog-in-android-phones) and [here](http://blog.sina.com.cn/s/blog_6f8d8d8e0100t7t7.html)):

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.speech.RecognitionListener;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
import android.speech.SpeechRecognizer;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.util.Log;



public class VoiceRecognitionTest extends Activity implements OnClickListener 
{

   private TextView mText;
   private SpeechRecognizer sr;
   private static final String TAG = "MyStt3Activity";
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
   {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            Button speakButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_speak);     
            mText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);     
            speakButton.setOnClickListener(this);
            sr = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this);       
            sr.setRecognitionListener(new listener());        
   }

   class listener implements RecognitionListener          
   {
            public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle params)
            {
                     Log.d(TAG, "onReadyForSpeech");
            }
            public void onBeginningOfSpeech()
            {
                     Log.d(TAG, "onBeginningOfSpeech");
            }
            public void onRmsChanged(float rmsdB)
            {
                     Log.d(TAG, "onRmsChanged");
            }
            public void onBufferReceived(byte[] buffer)
            {
                     Log.d(TAG, "onBufferReceived");
            }
            public void onEndOfSpeech()
            {
                     Log.d(TAG, "onEndofSpeech");
            }
            public void onError(int error)
            {
                     Log.d(TAG,  "error " +  error);
                     mText.setText("error " + error);
            }
            public void onResults(Bundle results)                   
            {
                     String str = new String();
                     Log.d(TAG, "onResults " + results);
                     ArrayList data = results.getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);
                     for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++)
                     {
                               Log.d(TAG, "result " + data.get(i));
                               str += data.get(i);
                     }
                     mText.setText("results: "+String.valueOf(data.size()));        
            }
            public void onPartialResults(Bundle partialResults)
            {
                     Log.d(TAG, "onPartialResults");
            }
            public void onEvent(int eventType, Bundle params)
            {
                     Log.d(TAG, "onEvent " + eventType);
            }
   }
   public void onClick(View v) {
            if (v.getId() == R.id.btn_speak) 
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);        
                intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
                intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE,"voice.recognition.test");

                intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS,5); 
                sr.startListening(intent);
                Log.i("111111","11111111");
            }
   }
}
```

Define main.xml with a button and give RECORD_AUDIO permission in manifest

Comment: came across this question while searching something else. Though its old question i thought posting the answer would be helpful for others

Comment: copied from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6316937/how-can-i-use-speech-recognition-without-the-annoying-dialog-in-android-phones :)

Comment: it always give output as either 5 or 4 or error 7

Result-5

Comment: Should be accepted as answer, its been 3 years now.

Comment: Just for clarity's sake, giving RECORD_AUDIO permission looks like `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />`.

Comment: is there a demo for the EXTRA_AUDIO_INJECT_SOURCE intent ? the doc only mentions it in passing.

Answer (score 3):

Also make sure to request the proper permissions from the user. I got stuck with an error 9 return value: INSUFFICIENT_PERMISSIONS, even though I had the proper RECORD_AUDIO permissions listed in the manifest.

In following the sample code [here](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) I was able to get the permissions from the user and then the speech recognizer returned good responses.

E.g. This block I put in my onCreate() for the activity, though it could go somewhere else in the UI flow, prior to calling the SpeechRecognizer methods:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        // Should we show an explanation?
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO)) {

            // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
            // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
            // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

        } else {

            // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO},
                    527);

            // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS is an
            // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
            // result of the request. (In this example I just punched in
            // the value 527)
        }
        ...
    }
```

Then provide a callback method in the activity for the permissions request:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 527: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                // permission was granted, yay! Do the
                // contacts-related task you need to do.

            } else {

                // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                // functionality that depends on this permission.
            }
            return;
        }

        // other 'case' lines to check for other
        // permissions this app might request
    }
}
```

One other thing I have to change in preetha's example code above where the resulting text is retrieved in the onResults() method. To get the actual text of the translated speech (rather than the size, as the original code prints) either print the value of the constructed string str or get one of the return values in the ArrayList (data). For instance:

```
.setText(data.get(0));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it as:

```
import android.app.Activity
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import android.widget.Toast
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent
import android.content.Intent

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val REQ_CODE = 100

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        speak.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH)
            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                    RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM)
            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE,  "ar-JO") //  Locale.getDefault()
            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Need to speak")
            try {
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_CODE)
            } catch (a: ActivityNotFoundException) {
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext,
                        "Sorry your device not supported",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

        when (requestCode) {
            REQ_CODE -> {
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null) {
                    val result = data
                            .getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS)
                    println("result: $result")
                    text.text = result[0]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `layout` could be simply:

```xml
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools = "http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width = "match_parent"
    android:layout_height = "match_parent"
    tools:context = ".MainActivity">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width = "match_parent"
        android:gravity = "center"
        android:layout_height = "match_parent">
        <TextView
            android:id = "@+id/text"
            android:textSize = "30sp"
            android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
            android:layout_height = "wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom = "true"
        android:layout_centerInParent = "true"
        android:orientation = "vertical"
        android:layout_height = "wrap_content">
        <ImageView
            android:id = "@+id/speak"
            android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
            android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
            android:background = "?selectableItemBackground"
            android:src = "@android:drawable/ic_btn_speak_now"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The other way which you are asking about, is little longer, but give you more control, also does not annoying you with Google Assistance dialouge:

1- First you need to grand permissions in the `Manifest` file:

```xml
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
```

2- I'm consolidating all the answers above, as:

- Create `RecognitionListener` class, as:

```
private val TAG = "Driver-Assistant"

class Listener(context: Context): RecognitionListener {
    private var ctx = context

    override fun onReadyForSpeech(params: Bundle?) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onReadyForSpeech")
    }

    override fun onRmsChanged(rmsdB: Float) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onRmsChanged")
    }

    override fun onBufferReceived(buffer: ByteArray?) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onBufferReceived")
    }

    override fun onPartialResults(partialResults: Bundle?) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onPartialResults")
    }

    override fun onEvent(eventType: Int, params: Bundle?) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onEvent")
    }

    override fun onBeginningOfSpeech() {
        Toast.makeText(ctx, "Speech started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }

    override fun onEndOfSpeech() {
        Toast.makeText(ctx, "Speech finished", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }

    override fun onError(error: Int) {
        var string = when (error) {
            6 -> "No speech input"
            4 -> "Server sends error status"
            8 -> "RecognitionService busy."
            7 -> "No recognition result matched."
            1 -> "Network operation timed out."
            2 -> "Other network related errors."
            9 -> "Insufficient permissions"
            5 -> " Other client side errors."
            3 -> "Audio recording error."
            else -> "unknown!!"
        }
        Toast.makeText(ctx, "sorry error occurred: $string", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }

    override fun onResults(results: Bundle?) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onResults $results")
        val data = results!!.getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION)
        display.text = data!![0]
    }
}
```

- In the main file you need to define `SpeechRecognizer`, adding the above `listner` to it, and do not forget asking for runtime permission, all together are below:

```
lateinit var sr: SpeechRecognizer
lateinit var display: TextView

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        display = text

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                        Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                            Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO)) {
            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        arrayOf(Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO),
                        527)
            }
        }

        sr = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this)
        sr.setRecognitionListener(Listener(this))

        speak.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH)
            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                    RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM)
            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE,  "ar-JO") //  Locale.getDefault()
            sr.startListening(intent)
        }

    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<out String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
        when (requestCode) {
            527  -> if (grantResults.isNotEmpty()
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                Toast.makeText(this, "Permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permission not granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SpeechRecognizer`, though I am not aware of any sample code for it beyond [this previous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4559930/speechrecognizer-causes-anr-i-need-help-with-android-speech-api). However, that is new to API level 8 (Android 2.2), and therefore is not widely usable at the time of this writing.

Comment: I wrote a test app trying to launch SpeechRecognizer.startListening() along with implemented listener methods, nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.android.example.speechtxt;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.speech.RecognitionListener;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
import android.speech.SpeechRecognizer;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Locale;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
    private SpeechRecognizer speechRecognizer;
    private Intent speechintent;
    String keeper="";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        checkVoiceCommandPermission();
        relativeLayout = findViewById(R.id.touchscr);

        speechRecognizer = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(getApplicationContext());
        speechintent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        speechintent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
        speechintent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());


        speechRecognizer.setRecognitionListener(new RecognitionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle params) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onBeginningOfSpeech() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onRmsChanged(float rmsdB) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onBufferReceived(byte[] buffer) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onEndOfSpeech() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(int error) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onResults(Bundle results)
            {
                ArrayList<String> speakedStringArray = results.getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);
                if(speakedStringArray!=null)
                {
                    keeper = speakedStringArray.get(0);

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+keeper,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onPartialResults(Bundle partialResults) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onEvent(int eventType, Bundle params) {

            }
        });

        relativeLayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction())
                {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        speechRecognizer.startListening(speechintent);
                        keeper="";
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        speechRecognizer.stopListening();
                        break;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }


    private void checkVoiceCommandPermission()
    {
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        {
            if (!(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO)== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED))
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS, Uri.parse("package:" +getPackageName()));
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }

        }
    }
}
```