# starting speech to text engine from a service

Tags: android, speech-to-text

I have a service from where I am trying to start a Speech to text engine ,but it's not working.. is it possible to start speech to text from a service?

MyService.java CLASS :

```
public class MyService extends Service{


OnActRes r;


EditText edittext;
//private Runnable m;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}




@Override
public void onCreate() {


            // TODO Auto-generated method stubry

    try
    {
               Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
               Toast.makeText(MyService.this,"STEP 1 !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
               intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE, getClass().getPackage().getName());
               Toast.makeText(MyService.this,"STEP 2 !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
               intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
               Toast.makeText(MyService.this,"STEP 3 !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
               //since we only want one, request 1
               intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 1);
               Toast.makeText(MyService.this,"STEP 4 !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
               intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, "en-US");
               Toast.makeText(MyService.this,"STEP 5 !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               r.startActivityForResult(intent, 1234);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(MyService.this,"ERROR here !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
    }




        }
```

}

Result.java

```
public class OnActRes extends Activity {


public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK){
        {
         Toast.makeText(OnActRes.this,"AR", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  

        ArrayList<String> matches = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
        String topResult = matches.get(0);

        Toast.makeText(OnActRes.this,topResult, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();   

}



    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

A few things you should check/change:

1. In your code, the activity reference `r` is null.
2. Why are you using a service for this? There's no reason to use a service in this case (It doesn't do anything in the background, it's only purpose is calling the recognizer activity - you can do that from your `OnActRes` activity).

If both didn't help, you can try using [Android's API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/SpeechRecognizer.html) for speech recognition, without using the recognition activity ([Example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4975443/is-there-a-way-to-use-the-speechrecognizer-api-directly-for-speech-input)). This can be called from a service, if you wish.

Comment: I want to make this speech-to-text conversion as a service in thread that is it will start listening and converting voice into text after some time. for this I want to make this activity as a service .
Is it possible ? Or any other better way of doing this suggested ?

Comment: If you want to call it in a service (Without disturbing your user interaction with other parts of the app) you should use the speech recognition API (Which I mentioned in my answer)