# Is there Speech to Text function in Android?

Tags: android, text

or is there any library that I can use?

What I want is to record a audio, and then display the text recognized. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, please do a google search next time, http://code4reference.com/2012/07/tutorial-android-voice-recognition/

Alternately, if you want more control you can use SpeechRecognizer, [Is there a way to use the SpeechRecognizer API directly for speech input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4975443/is-there-a-way-to-use-the-speechrecognizer-api-directly-for-speech-input)