# Null Exception During Init of Speech Recognition on Android

Tags: android, speech-recognition

I'm working for the speech recognition for my application and I tried this code and
I'm getting the error in my logcat as **intent must not null exception** in android

```
    public class SpeechRecognizerActivity extends Activity {
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        String a;
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
           final TextView txt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            class MyRecognitionListener implements RecognitionListener {

                            @Override
                            public void onBeginningOfSpeech() {
                                    Log.d("Speech", "onBeginningOfSpeech");
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onBufferReceived(byte[] buffer) {
                                    Log.d("Speech", "onBufferReceived");
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onEndOfSpeech() {
                                    Log.d("Speech", "onEndOfSpeech");
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onError(int error) {
                                    Log.d("Speech", "onError");
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onEvent(int eventType, Bundle params) {
                                    Log.d("Speech", "onEvent");
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onPartialResults(Bundle partialResults) {
                                    Log.d("Speech", "onPartialResults");
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle params) {
                                    Log.d("Speech", "onReadyForSpeech");
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onResults(Bundle results) {
                                    Log.d("Speech", "onResults");
                                    ArrayList<String> strlist = results.getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);
                                    for (int i = 0; i < strlist.size();i++ ) {
                                            Log.d("Speech", "result=" + strlist.get(i));
                                    }

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onRmsChanged(float rmsdB) {
                                    Log.d("Speech", "onRmsChanged");
                            }

            }
            SpeechRecognizer sr = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(getApplicationContext());
            MyRecognitionListener listener = new MyRecognitionListener();
            sr.setRecognitionListener(listener);
   sr.startListening(RecognizerIntent.getVoiceDetailsIntent(getApplicationContext()));
         }
    }
```

Please suggest me, what i'm making mistake or have to set something setting previously in 
the emulator before running the program.

Comment: What are you doing in your code? How are you trying to recognize voice i just can't understand?!!! Have you preferred any tutorial for this before implmenting ?

Comment: Check out this http://www.vogella.com/code/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/VoiceRecognition.html

Comment: @GrIsHu I think user2582340 doesn't want to open the speech input activity and thus tries to use the SpeechRecognizer, as asked ans answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6316937/how-can-i-use-speech-recognition-without-the-annoying-dialog-in-android-phones

Comment: Any results so far? Did one of the answers work out for you?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you're going in the right direction when trying to create the `Intent` for your `SpeechRecognizer` with `RecognizerIntent.getVoiceDetailsIntent(getApplicationContext())`, as there are some restrictions using this method according to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognizerIntent.html#getVoiceDetailsIntent%28android.content.Context%29). These restrictions might lead to `null` returned by the function.

Try the following instead:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);        
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE,"voice.recognition.test"); // Replace by your package.
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS,5); 
sr.startListening(intent);
```

as suggested by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4975443/is-there-a-way-to-use-the-speechrecognizer-api-directly-for-speech-input) SO thread.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know whether you properly understood the VoiceRecognization or not. But Google provides an option to search the web using voice command .

Voice recognition featured in android is achieved using the **RecognizerIntent**.Use the Recognizer class in an intent to call the voice API.Here we check for the recognizer in the device if available the speech to text happen else we show a toast displaying 'Recognizer Not Found'

```
private void startVoiceRecognitionActivity()
{
Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "AndroidBite Voice Recognition...");
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
}
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
     if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
     {
         ArrayList<String> matches = data.getStringArrayListExtra(
          RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
           resultList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
matches));
      }
   super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
}
```

Check out [demo](http://androidbite.blogspot.in/2013/04/android-voice-recognition-example.html)