# Increase a seek bar when speech is input in android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, speech-recognition, seekbar

So I'm making an app, and I need a meter (seek bar) to increase when a person speaks. Is this even possible to do? and how would I go about achiving this?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it shows no OP's initiative to solve the problem by himself

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this?
http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/seek-bars.html

Or progress bar?
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html

For which you just `setProgress(int)` with your values.

Comment: im trying to use the code from this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4975443/is-there-a-way-to-use-the-speechrecognizer-api-directly-for-speech-input - to change the progress of a seekbar using setProgress(int) but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: I don't see a progress bar in your link. If you think SpeechRecognizer then it doesn't have function like setProgress(int). Check documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/SpeechRecognizer.html

Comment: The link isn't anything to do with a progress bar. I'm trying to make an app that has a progress bar increase, when someone speaks

Comment: But the link you gave from which you're using the code, there are no progress bars.

Comment: Ok, let try to explain this again. I know that code has no progress bars. I am trying to make an app in which you press a button, then speak. The app acknowledges that someone has spoken, and then increases a progress bar. The issue I'm having is I can not for the life of me get this to work. - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4975443/is-there-a-way-to-use-the-speechrecognizer-api-directly-for-speech-input - this is just the code I'm using for the voice recognition.