# Hide Google Voice recognition

Tags: android, speech-recognition, voice

I'm using Google Voice recognition and would like to hide the popup with Google and the mic that is being shown.. This is my code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(
                    RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);

            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, getResources().getString(R.string.ttslang));

            try {
                startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_SPEECH);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException a) {
                Toast t = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        getResources().getString(R.string.notts),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                t.show();
            }
```

As I think that I already saw such apps, I think that this is possible.. If it is, does somebody know how?

Many thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I use speech recognition without the annoying dialog in android phones](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6316937/how-can-i-use-speech-recognition-without-the-annoying-dialog-in-android-phones)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For that, you need to use [SpeechRecognizer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/SpeechRecognizer.html). An example can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10222745/3848666).

It's quite easy to implement:

```
SpeechRecognizer recognizer = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this);       
recognizer.setRecognitionListener(new RecognitionListener() { ... });
```

The listener catches the events and you process them accordingly.

Comment: add some code snippet here so user get overall idea

Comment: With every code I saw, I can only get a string array. How can I just get the "best result" (I already got with Google Voice Input)?

Comment: Just getting the first element of the returning array, still thanks